# Looping through worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am a beginner to VBA (started 3 days ago) trying to build a macro. I hope to get help with my code as well as to understand what is going on with the code in the parts that I went wrong.

The objective of the code is to collect values from cells in the last column of every worksheet and compile them into a bank column in the first sheet (that I will create upon first opening the Worksheet).

My code is is very raw and possibly contains many errors. It is, for the most parts, copied and pasted from sources (even from the macro recorder). I have managed to make it work but I hope to condense it. The code that works is:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    ' Creating a bank sheet
    Sheets.Add

    ' Returning to Page 1
    Sheets("Page 1").Activate

    ' Use all cells on the sheet "Page 1"
    Set rng = Sheets("Page 1").Cells

    ' Find the last column in "Page 1" and COPY
    LastCol = Last(2, rng)
    rng(2, LastCol).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' Paste Selection in Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

    ' Reset cursor to next blank space
    Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    ' Repeat for Page 2
    Sheets("Page 2").Activate
    Set rng = Sheets("Page 2").Cells
    LastCol = Last(2, rng)
    rng(2, LastCol).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

    ' Reset cursor to next blank space
    Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    ' Repeat for Page 3
    Sheets("Page 3").Activate
    Set rng = Sheets("Page 3").Cells
    LastCol = Last(2, rng)
    rng(2, LastCol).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

    ' Selecting range to sort
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells
    LastCell = Last(3, rng)
    With rng.Parent
        .Select
        .Range("A1", LastCell).Select
    End With

    ' Sorting
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A177"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:A176")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

This will not work for workbooks with a different number of worksheets. I have made attempts to condense it by finding the number of worksheets and looping through them, but I am unable to further understand from online sources. This is what I have tried to do:

```
    For N = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

    ' Use all cells on active sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(N).Select
    Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Cells

    ' Find the last column in active sheet and COPY
    LastCol = Last(2, rng)
    rng(2, LastCol).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    ' Paste Selection in Sheet1
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

    ' Reset cursor to next blank space
    Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next N
```

Unfortunately this code does not work.

How can I create a loop to achieve what I have been able to do with my first code?

Relevant functions I have used in my code are shown below (courtesy from Ron De Bruin):

```
Function Last(choice As Long, rng As Range)
'Ron de Bruin, 5 May 2008
' 1 = last row
' 2 = last column
' 3 = last cell
Dim lrw As Long
Dim lcol As Long

Select Case choice

Case 1:
    On Error Resume Next
    Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

Case 2:
    On Error Resume Next
    Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0

Case 3:
    On Error Resume Next
    lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                   After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                   Lookat:=xlPart, _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                   MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                    Lookat:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0

    On Error Resume Next
    Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
    If Err.Number > 0 Then
        Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
        Err.Clear
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

End Select
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Column
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: First, I'd take a lot the time cleaning up all of the selects and activates from your code.  Those statements tend to  makes it *a lot* more difficult to follow.  Next, I'd research how to fully qualify your range references.  That will make sure your code is executing where you want it to. The problem with someone just solving this specific problem for you is, you'll be right back here when you have another problem.  Better to understand your code so you can fix /modify it down the road.

Comment: Thank you @sous2817. I have tried to the best of my ability before asking this question, consulting books and forums. I hope you can help me understand where I went wrong.

Comment: As said above the selecting and activating are slowing things down and making it difficult to read.  That said, one problem is this `Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Cells`.  Change it to `Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hopefully get you started.  First, here is the same code that should do the same thing, as far as I can tell.  It copies the last row of your "Page" worksheets after removing all of the selects and activates:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRowDestination As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Sheet1"

    With Sheets("Page 1")
        LastCol = Last(2, .Cells)
        LastRow = Last(1, .Cells(1, LastCol).EntireColumn)

        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
        NextRowDestination = Last(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn) + 1
    End With

    With Sheets("Page 2")
        LastCol = Last(2, .Cells)
        LastRow = Last(1, .Cells(1, LastCol).EntireColumn)

        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

        rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRowDestination, 1)
        NextRowDestination = Last(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn) + 1
    End With

    With Sheets("Page 3")
        LastCol = Last(2, .Cells)
        LastRow = Last(1, .Cells(1, LastCol).EntireColumn)

        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

        rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRowDestination, 1)
        NextRowDestination = Last(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn) + 1
    End With

End Sub
```

As you can see, it's easy to tell what is happening for each sheet.  Also, you'll quickly notice that you have a lot of duplicate code!  Perfect place for a loop (AND you can get your main question of 'What if I have more than 3 sheets?' answered for free)!

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim NextRowDestination As Long

    Dim rng As Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = "Sheet1"

    NextRowDestination = 2

    For counter = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If Left(Worksheets(counter).Name, 4) = "Page" Then

            Set ws = Worksheets(counter)

            With ws
                LastCol = Last(2, .Cells)
                LastRow = Last(1, .Cells(1, LastCol).EntireColumn)

                Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, LastCol), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

                rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(NextRowDestination, 1)
                NextRowDestination = Last(1, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn) + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Now keep in mind, I made a few assumptions as without seeing your data structure, it was hard for me to visualize:
   1) You don't want to copy over any header rows
   2) The sheet you're creating doesn't have a header row, and the data starts being copied over at row 2.
   3) I didn't do anything with your sort code, as I wasn't entirely sure what you were doing there.
   4) I didn't build in any checking for duplicate Sheet1 or anything like that.  Error handling should be taken in to account.

But the Test2 code above should get you really close to what you're trying to do (minus the sort bit).

Comment: Thank you so much for the code! It's really much cleaner than mine. You showed me a few things there, 

(1) that I could use some kind of validation to make vba work on worksheets with the text "page", which makes it dynamic for other worksheets that I might encounter in the future.

(2) You used ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count while i used ThisWorkbook. and perhaps that was why my code did not loop.

To be able to do so much without looking at my data structure, you're really good! It did get me really close to what I'm trying to do, Thanks again! (:

Comment: Glad I could help!  If you feel this answered helped you (or will help others), feel free to mark it as accepted and/or upvote it.  If you get jammed up again, please post a new question.  Good luck with the rest of your project!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub makeBank()
    Dim bnk As Worksheet, lrBnk As Long, ur As Range, rngBnk As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet, fr As Long, lr As Long, lc As Long, rngThis As Range

    enableXl False                                      'disable screen and alerts
    With Application.ActiveWorkbook
        For Each ws In .Worksheets                      'go through all sheets
           If ws.Name = "Bank" Then ws.Delete: Exit For 'and remove bnk sheet if exists
        Next
        .Worksheets.Add Before:=.Worksheets(1)          'add new sheet before all others
        Set bnk = .Worksheets(1)                        'set a reference to the new sheet
        bnk.Name = "Bank"                               'rename it

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Bank" Then                   'exclude bnk sheet
                fr = ws.UsedRange.Row                   'first used row on current sheet
                lr = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count            'last used row on current sheet
                lc = ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count         'last used col on current sheet

                Set ur = bnk.UsedRange                  'used range on bnk
                lrBnk = ur.Row + ur.Rows.Count          'last used row on bnk

                Set rngBnk = bnk.Range(bnk.Cells(lrBnk, 1), bnk.Cells(lrBnk + lr - 1, 1))
                Set rngThis = ws.Range(ws.Cells(fr, lc), ws.Cells(lr, lc))

                rngBnk.Value2 = rngThis.Value2          'append this last col to bnk's 1st
            End If
        Next
        bnk.Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete                    'delete first (extra) row on bnk
        sortCol bnk.UsedRange.Columns(1)                'sort first column on bnk sheet
    End With
    enableXl True                                       'enable screen and alerts
End Sub
```

---

Other functions used:

```
Private Sub sortCol(ByVal col As Range)
    With col.Parent.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=col, Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange col
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub enableXl(ByVal opt As Boolean)
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = opt
        .DisplayAlerts = opt
    End With
End Sub
```

---

How the main Sub works (makeBank)

- If a worksheet named "Bank" exists it deletes it
- Creates a new "Bank" sheet
- Moves through all sheets, except "Bank", and

  - determines first used row, last used row, and last used column on current sheet
  - determines first empty row on "Bank" (plus offset by rows copied)
  - copies last used column on current sheet and appends it to the first empty row on Bank
  - moves to the next sheet
- In the first iteration it generates an empty row on Bank, so at the end it removes it
- sorts the column of data on Bank

Comment: Thanks for your code! Your annotations helped me plenty with understanding! Your code worked perfectly! Except I was trying to compile the copied columns into just one bank column.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I updated it to append all last columns into a single bank column, as a reference